# Consume an external api in C# mvc without any model , just simply in xml format

Tags: asp.net-mvc, rest, api, asp.net-web-api

I am having an external webapi whose url is this : https://dhi.eoffice.gov.in/eFileServices/rest/xmldataset/efile/filecreatedsectionwise

i tried it in postman and the data is getting fetched in post method, but i am not able to consume this api in my mvc application. Till now i have tried searching google but didnt got exact answer

I tried making a class and using the class to consume api in table, but didnt got any result

```
 public class HomeController : Controller
    {
        string baseurl = "https://dhi.eoffice.gov.in/eFileServices/";


            public async Task<ActionResult> Index()
            {
                List<dhi> dhinfo = new List<dhi>();

                using (var client = new HttpClient())
                {
                    //Passing service base url  
                    client.BaseAddress = new Uri(baseurl);
                    //client.Headers["Content-type"] = "application/xml";
                    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Clear();
                    //Define request data format  
                    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));

                    //Sending request to find web api REST service resource GetAllEmployees using HttpClient  
                    HttpResponseMessage Res = await client.GetAsync("rest/xmldataset/efile/filecreatedsectionwise");

                    //Checking the response is successful or not which is sent using HttpClient  
                    if (Res.IsSuccessStatusCode)
                    {
                        //Storing the response details recieved from web api   
                        var EmpResponse = Res.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;

                        //Deserializing the response recieved from web api and storing into the Employee list  
                        dhinfo = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<dhi>>(EmpResponse);

                    }
                    //returning the employee list to view  
                    return View(dhinfo);
                }
            }
```

```
@model IEnumerable<eofficeWepApi.Models.dhi>


<table class="table table-responsive" style="width:400px">
    <tr>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.departmentid)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.departmentname)
        </th>

        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.efilecreated)
        </th>

        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.orgid)
        </th>

        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.orgname)
        </th>

        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.pfilecreated)
        </th>

        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.total)
        </th>
    </tr>

    @foreach (var item in Model)
    {
    <tr>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.departmentid)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.departmentname)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.efilecreated)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.orgid)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.orgname)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.pfilecreated)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.total)
        </td>
    </tr>
    }

</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Kindly Check what type of API you are consuming, whether it is a Rest service or WCF service .
If it is a Service you need to add the service reference from that you can consume the api methods.
You can get the code for the above api part, in the postman itself: copy and past that code in your project.

Comment: what am i doing wrong in my code, can u pls tell, and the api which i am consuming is rest service

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
using (var client = new HttpClient())
                {
                    request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
                  //  request.KeepAlive = false;

    //here check for the authentication headers if any
                    request.PreAuthenticate = true;

                    //For JSON Response .....
                    request.Method = "GET";
                    request.ContentType = "application/json";

                    response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();

                    string s = response.ToString();
                    StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream());
                    result = reader.ReadToEnd().Trim();
                }
```

Comment: what should i return in view, if i dont return anything, it doesn't show anything

Comment: Store the api result in to the Model properties and then pass in to the View , SO you can use your class model properties in the View.

Comment: when i am using your code, it shows an error in console The character encoding of the plain text document was not declared. The document will render with garbled text in some browser configurations if the document contains characters from outside the US-ASCII range. The character encoding of the file needs to be declared in the transfer protocol or file needs to use a byte order mark as an encoding signature. localhost:58389

​

Comment: Is your api is authenticated ? and return the response in which format?

Comment: i tried to call the api from postman and its showing the output in xml format, and i am using the same url in the postman as well, the api which i am trying to consume is using rest

Comment: BY using the content type =application/json you can change the respose to json try  on postman, then in postman you can see the c# code for the api consume. You can use this same code in your project to cosume the api.

Comment: there may be network issue , or the service accessbility issue with that code and also the api authentication issue